# MongoDb Exiting with Code: 100

Tags: mongodb

I know that there are other questions similar to this, but they do not have the same exact log and I have tried many supposed solutions that haven't worked. This is my log:

```
2018-05-16T00:31:32.193-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16976 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Edan
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.1
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-05-16T00:31:32.194-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I think that I closed my terminal window before shutting down the server, and now I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the log `Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating`. You're already running another `mongod` instance. Shut it down before launching another or realize it's already running.

Comment: `killall mongod` on *nix based platforms. End the process from task manager on windows. Or open a `mongo` shell and do `use admin` and then `db.shutdownServer()` to be more safe.

Comment: I was trying to close windows and didn't think to run that command - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the log that "Another mongod instance is already running" and you need to gracefully shut down it before starting the server again.

If it didn't work, forcefully kill the mongod process and remove the lock file.

If you are on unix environment,

1. Run **ps -A | grep mongo**
2. Copy the process id(s)
3. Run **kill -9 [process id]**

And then remove the mongo lock file

1. Run **sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock**